# 404Not Found error returned for Spring REST calls

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

I am trying to expose my existing web application through web services. For this I have created a REST controller to handle rest calls. I am not sure if I need to change the existing web configurations for web services to work. Below is the URL I am using to access the resources.

> http://localhost:9090/HospitalProject/rest/patient/Solo100

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/patient")
public class PatientRESTController {

@RequestMapping(path="/{name}", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Patient> getPatientByName(@PathVariable("name") String name){
    Patient patient = patientService.findPatient(name);
    return new ResponseEntity<Patient>(patient, HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

---

```
public class ApplicationIntializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext springContext= new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    springContext.register(ApplicationConfig.class);
    springContext.setServletContext(servletContext);

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcherServlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(springContext));
    dispatcherServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcherServlet.addMapping("/");
}

}
```

---

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.hp"})
@EnableWebMvc
public class ApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    return viewResolver;
}

public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer){
    configurer.enable();
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried wiithout "HospitalProject", maybe your context root is not where you expect

Comment: @karelss I believe the context will remain the same for the web application and service?

Comment: Yes, sorry i didn't read the part of the webapp, i thought that's was a standalone webservices app

Comment: Did you set `server.context-path` in `application.yml` or `application.proprties`? Otherwise set it to `server.context-path=/HospitalProject`